# Accessing Community's profile "all actions" tab timeout

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user

Okay, This *might* not be something everyone does...
But anyway I just tried to access [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)'s profile "all actions" tab, without filter : 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort= (note the lack of `sort` parameter), 
and it times out after about 30 seconds of server loading.
**I tried 2 times to make sure it's not just a random bug.**
Is there a missing `LIMIT` in the SQL request ?? (I don't know, it's just a hypothesis based on my programming experience)
I get redirected to the following page : https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/-1/community (Which is a nice error page though.)

It doesn't timeout on other sites like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) or [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity).

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. Editing my post...

Comment: You like annoying [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)?

Comment: @rene you need to say his name three times to summon him. Nick Craver, Nick Craver, Nick Craver!

Comment: IIRC sql commands have a commandtimeout of 5 or 10 seconds or so and after that raise an exception. This is to prevent the application layer will get bogged down by one suboptimal query that causes trouble on large datasets.

Comment: This is what I understood, but with `LIMIT` and some pagination (with AJAX requests), we could have non-laggy loading.. (and therefore no timeout)

Comment: Just trying to load the activity summary takes a surprisingly long time for a page with barely anything on it. Not quite an error page like the "all actions" tab, but it feels like it's almost enough to hit a timeout.

Comment: The request fails, saying that things "crash" is pretty much the same as yelling "fire!" when your cat is stuck up a tree :)

Comment: @Gimby I don't know, I don't own a cat... Seriously speaking, you're right, and I fixed it.

Comment: Reproduced.....

Comment: Well the first time it loads with no things as @user2357112 said and then it shows the error page for me. ([tag:status-reproduced])

Comment: @rene The default is 30 seconds so this being a timeout seems reasonable.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Minor point, but SO uses SQL Server which doesn't use `LIMIT`. Instead you would do something like this `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Id OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: @DavidG I was mentioning the timeouts as used by SE (not the .Net defaults)  as I recall Nick mentioned that somewhere, either in a (b|v)log, tweet, a post, a comment or chat but I can't find that source right now. It struck me as being a low setting which gives the need for a tuned db and no surprises with query plan selection.

Comment: I'm looking into the timeout issue with this query. I think I've figured out what part of the query is the problem, I'm now digging into how we can rewrite/tune it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, Jean-Marc! Taryn, and later Nick as well, have been cracking on this particular pain-point for most of the last week... And I'm happy to report that Community's actions list just loaded for me in under 30 seconds!

The root issue here wasn't the lack of a limit; it's that Community had almost three million actions of various sorts associated with it - so SQL Server had to accumulate all of them, count them... And then accumulate them *again* in order to grab the correct page. That... Took a while. Long enough to time out.

The first step to solving this was to get rid of a bunch of those actions: one of the things attributed to Community were the various URL rewriting tasks we've done in the past. Those were nice to have listed somewhere at the time, but we don't really need 1.7 million of them listed there forever - so most of them are now attributed to "URL Rewriter Bot", with no profile linked:

[image: Screenshot: URL Rewriter Bot rewrites a URL]

That brought the total number of actions down under a million... But the query was still timing out. Easy solutions exhausted, Taryn spent the next few days tearin' through one variation of the query after another, analyzing each piece to find the pain points and looking for a set of optimizations or hints sufficient to allow it to complete in time. Today, with a healthy bit of assistance from Nick Craver, she's brought it under control:

[image: The count query executing in 6566.1ms] [image: The page query executing in 16667ms]

The page itself will load a *bit* more slowly than the two numbers above suggest, of course: there are a lot of other heavy queries that need to run to render the entire profile. But this is still a massive improvement - and it should confer a small benefit to folks viewing the profiles of *other* very active users as well.

Thanks again for taking the time to post this report, and thanks also to Taryn & Nick for taking the time to work through a fix!